# Return MySQL Count via PHP

Tags: php

I have a PHP function that looks like this:

```
function count_creatives() {
    global $db;
    $q = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT creative) FROM actions";
    return $db->query($q);
}
```

The $db variable contains a PDO object and is set correctly (used successfully elsewhere).

When I try to assign the result of this function to a variable, it only contains the querystring (no results).

Code I'm Running:

`$count = count_creatives();`

`echo $count;`

Output:

`PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT creative) FROM actions )`

Any idea why I'm not getting the actual count (e.g. 2, 3, 100)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning the resource object from your function, not the field value. You need to fetch the result and then return that. Please use the following:

```
function count_creatives() 
{
    global $db;
    $q = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT creative) AS `total` FROM actions";
    $result = $db->query($q);
    $actions = $result->fetchObject();

    return $actions->total;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[PDO::query()](https://www.php.net/pdo.query) returns a PDOStatement object, or FALSE on failure.  You need to do something like,

```
function count_creatives() {
    global $db;
    $q = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT creative) FROM actions";
    $query = $db->query($q);
    return $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)[0];
}
```

Comment: `count_creatives()` will return an array, not the count.